# select with varchar and int, money value in table

Tags: sql-server-2008, rdbms

I wrote below query:

```
SELECT Name, salary + ',' + Branch + ' , ' + PhNumber AS address 
FROM tablename;
```

my error is : Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your column **salary** is of datatype: `money` and, column **PhNumber** is of type: `numeric`. And you are trying to concatenate it with `char` column: `Branch`.

Need to Cast it as:

```
SELECT Name, CAST(salary as VARCHAR(20)) + ',' + Branch + ' , ' 
            + CAST(PhNumber as VARCHAR(20)) AS address 
FROM tablename;
```

Comment: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: ok it means, your  phone number also is of different datatype.. you haven't mentioned it in Question